# React-Native: How to create an UI with blur

Tags: android, user-interface, react-native

I have been struggling for the past few days but have not found a solution to implement this UI (I have attached the photo). Please help me.
I have visited react-native-blur but buildToolsVersion is '25 .0.3 '(I can't decide to edit it on 23.xx) and get this error when I try to use buildToolsVersion 25.0.3: "Native component for 'BlurView' does not exist "

Link Photo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PiNDvPTrrWiZU8VLQj3DsczuC2-ssm_s/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The implementation for Android is a bit different as you need to use findNodeHandle and make reference to the blurred components. Here is the sample code that works for me:

https://gist.github.com/harixth/d9414a63a859b2e19b13d9915fcaa00c